# How to show username who has clicked on a button in slack using custom message builder

Tags: slack

Im trying to display who clicked on "Yes" and who clicked on "No". Here is my code.

```
"channel": SLACK_CHANNEL,
        "text": "Would you like to promote the build to production?",
        "attachments": [
            {
                "text": "Yes to deploy your build to production",
                "fallback": "You are unable to promote a build",
                "callback_id": "Put the callback_id for the action",
                "color": "#SomeColourHere",
                "attachment_type": "default",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "deployment",
                        "text": "Yes",
                        "style": "danger",
                        "type": "button",
                        "value": json.dumps({"approve": True, "codePipelineToken": token, "codePipelineName": codepipeline_name}),
                        "confirm": {
                            "title": "Are you sure?",
                            "text": "This will deploy the build to production",
                            "ok_text": "Yes",
                            "dismiss_text": "No"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "deployment",
                        "text": "No",
                        "type": "button",
                        "value": json.dumps({"approve": False, "codePipelineToken": token, "codePipelineName": codepipeline_name})
                    }  
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Is there any way that we can show who clicked on those buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided insufficient details, but I can confirm that you can figure out who clicked the buttons.

The code seems to be legacy from the looks of it.
Slack recommends the use of block kit to construct interactive messages now.

For your solution, when you capture the event raised by the button click,
'user' details are sent as part of the payload.

Please check here for details: https://api.slack.com/legacy/interactive-messages

Comment: could you please post any of the sample code here